# Why do these Youtube elements (suggestion-list-items) have same id

Tags: html, youtube

This looks weird to me:

[image]

Take a look at the screen shot above taken from Youtube. Can someone please explain what purpose does it serve to have same IDs(`dismissable`, `dismissed`) for multiple elements?
These are the suggestion videos on the right side while another video is playing as in the screenshot below:

[image]

Answer (score 11, accepted):

The HTML validator: https://validator.w3.org/ shows that 
YouTube and, in fact, many Google websites as not HTML compliant.

*Note*: I tested a copy of the HTML because using the URL will crop some HTML that is rendered after the page is loaded.

I analyzing the required page and it showed more than 1000 html errors. See error #1001 below:

[image]

Regarding your question. The said ID is duplicate and this is not allowed in HTML. The ID was used for CSS styling (which is a bad practice to format multiple elements using the id. The good practice is to use the class. See:
[image]

**Conclusion**
Google websites are bad examples for learners of professional programming. In fact, I once wrote an article on LinkedIn how Google asks websites to comply to some SEO rules, however, non of Google's websites follow their own rules of SEO. See my [article](https://www.linkedin.com/pulse/seo-dictatorship-google-search-engine-shadi-namrouti/) on Linkedin for more details.

Answer (score 0):

Dont know exactly why they are using ID's.

whenever you are clicking the **Not Interested** in your suggested video they are showing this **dismissed** div with some options like **UNDO, TELL US WHY**

[image: Screenshot]

Answer (score 0):

It is entirely possible to have multiple elements with the same ID. It's not generally best practice, but it does have its occasional uses. As for how selectors would work, if you're going in knowing you'll have conflicting IDs you could use your selectors with a parent, where the IDs under the parent would be unique. eg $('div#car span#size) and $('div#truck span#size').

Multiple IDs can, in practice, be replaced by using classes.
However, classes are intended for applying styles, not identifying elements, making the scope of names much wider and therefore likely to overlap. Especially if using 3rd party libraries. Id as 'identifier' is not intended to be multiplied so there is clearly a need for something in between. The practical use is componentization of sections of a page/dom into separate logical units. Using (at least) 2-layer identification is hence required.